# Meme won't display in designated file only

Tags: graphics, display

I have a meme on my computer that I am trying to insert into a file, something I have done hundreds of times.   It won't go into this specific file despite my having many others in the file.

I copied the working code exactly only changing the meme name and it won't work.  I can't place the meme anywhere in the file.   I erase 90% of the file (everything prior except the heading) and it still won't come up.   I can copy the same exact code in another file and it works fine.   I can change the name and it won't come up.   I can put a different graphic in there and it won't come up, entirely different from the meme.
Let me show you.
`<img src="test2.jpg" alt="some_text" class="responsive" style="max-     width:100%; height:auto; padding: 5px;"> <br /><br /> <img src="labinmontana.jpg" alt="some more text" class="responsive" style="max-width:100%; height:auto; padding: 5px;"> <br />`
The test2 is an entirely different graphic and it won't come up.   I see the alternate text.  If I erase everything but the file name I see that little symbol on the computer indicating something is there.
`<img src="test2.jpg">`
I don't get it.  It works in an entirely different file, several in fact.   I don't claim to be a whiz at this but something this simple, it almost sounds like there is something in the file that won't allow this or these to be displayed yet what could that be that disallows not just one file but several.   Too many files??  Well, I see something I haven't tried, I'll copy one from another working file into this one, same place..   That works fine..  This makes no sense.  I'm afraid it will be something stupid but I sure don't see it.

Ok I copied a similar chunk of code from a different file to this one, and it works fine, brings up the graphic.  I just change the name to the graphic (memme) and it won't come up.   again, it will in other files and will display on my computer if I click on it.

Update--  If I take out the line
`<base href="https://www.dumbellnebula.com">`
out of the header, the meme (a small graphic) will display.  I can do without the line, I just don't know why that would happen.

gem

Comment: Can you please post the code that is giving you trouble? Without it, we won't be of much help.

Comment: I did answer this once..  `<img src="labinmontana.jpg" alt="Some text" class="responsive" style="max-width:100%; height:auto; padding: 5px;">`   I could not get this to display, no way, no how, it is just a simple little graphic.  It would work in any other files just fine.  I finally deleted `<base href="https://www.dumbellnebula.com">` from the heading and it now works.   Makes no sense to me.